# installing apache 2 in ubuntu

Tags: installation, java, sudo, apache2

Hello I am new to ubuntu. I am trying to install Apache2 using "sudo apt-get install apache2" command.I have set my java path as per rules but still its showing me this following errors:

```
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcommons-dbcp-java:
 libcommons-dbcp-java depends on default-jre-headless | java2-runtime-headless; however:
  Package default-jre-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java7-installer which provides default-jre-headless is not configured yet.
  Package java2-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package oracle-java7-installer which provides java2-runtime-headless is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libcommons-dbcp-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtomcat6-java:
 libtomcat6-java depends on libcommons-dbcp-java; however:
  Package libcommons-dbcp-java is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libtomcat6-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tomcat6-common:
 tomcat6-common depends on libtomcat6-java (>= 6.0.32-5ubuntu1.2); however:
  Package libtomcat6-java is not conNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                              No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                      No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                  No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                            figured yet.
dpkg: error processing tomcat6-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tomcat6:
 tomcat6 depends on tomcat6-common (>= 6.0.32-5ubuntu1.2); however:
  Package tomcat6-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing tomcat6 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tomcat6-admin:
 tomcat6-admin depends on tomcat6-common (>= 6.0.32-5ubuntu1.2); however:
  Package tomcat6-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing tomcat6-admin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tomcat6-docs:
 tomcat6-docs depends on tomcat6-common (>= 6.0.32-5ubuntu1.2); however:
  Package tomcat6-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing tomcat6-docs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tomcat6-examples:
 tomcat6-examples depends on tomcat6-common (>= 6.0.32-5ubuntu1.2); however:
  Package tomcat6-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing tomcat6-examples (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tomcat6-user:
 tomcat6-user depends on tomcat6-common (>= 6.0.32-5ubuntu1.2); however:
  Package tomcat6-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing tomcat6-user (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
 libcommons-dbcp-java
 libtomcat6-java
 tomcat6-common
 tomcat6
 tomcat6-admin
 tomcat6-docs
 tomcat6-examples
 tomcat6-user
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@sheetal:/home/prakash/Downloads#
```

Comment: There are dependency problems, try running `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix dependency issues. http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is Oracle Java you have installed? If not installing Oracle Java in Ubuntu requires something like on this link:
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html